# JPA - No Datasource

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

Trying to create a simple crud application with JPA 2.0 and Eclipselink running JAVA EE 6. I'm currently using netbeans and using a JSF project for the web. I've create a book class and have tried to insert data from the main class. However when I run the project I"m getting errors.

Persistence.xml:

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <persistence version="2.0"
> xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
> http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">  
> <persistence-unit name="JavaWebPU" transaction-type="JTA">
>     <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
>     <jta-data-source>openx</jta-data-source>
>     <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
>     <properties>
>       <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
>     </properties>   </persistence-unit> </persistence>
```

I've also checked glassfish admin console and have determined the database and connection pool.

Output:

```
Jun 10, 2013 3:52:59 PM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.0.Final
[EL Info]: 2013-06-10 15:52:59.691--ServerSession(4911604)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461
Jun 10, 2013 3:53:03 PM com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ActiveRAFactory createActiveResourceAdapter
SEVERE: RAR6001 : Class Not found : com.sun.gjc.spi.ResourceAdapterImpl
Jun 10, 2013 3:53:03 PM com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ActiveRAFactory createActiveResourceAdapter
SEVERE: 
com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Error in creating active RAR
[EL Severe]: 2013-06-10 15:53:03.16--ServerSession(4911604)--Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [openx].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'openx' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to look up ConnectorDescriptor from JNDI [Root exception is com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Error in creating active RAR]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ActiveRAFactory.createActiveResourceAdapter(ActiveRAFactory.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ResourceAdapterAdminServiceImpl.createActiveResourceAdapter(ResourceAdapterAdminServiceImpl.java:212)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.createActiveResourceAdapter(ConnectorRuntime.java:379)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.naming.ConnectorObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ConnectorObjectFactory.java:108)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getObjectInstance(SerialContext.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:514)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:654)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:272)
    at com.book.Main.main(Main.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.gjc.spi.ResourceAdapterImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ActiveRAFactory.createActiveResourceAdapter(ActiveRAFactory.java:101)
    ... 19 more

Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [openx].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'openx' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to look up ConnectorDescriptor from JNDI [Root exception is com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Error in creating active RAR]]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:272)
    at com.book.Main.main(Main.java:31)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [openx].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'openx' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to look up ConnectorDescriptor from JNDI [Root exception is com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Error in creating active RAR]]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.cannotAcquireDataSource(ValidationException.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:488)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'openx' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to look up ConnectorDescriptor from JNDI [Root exception is com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Error in creating active RAR]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:654)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:103)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to look up ConnectorDescriptor from JNDI [Root exception is com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Error in creating active RAR]
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.naming.ConnectorObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ConnectorObjectFactory.java:115)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getObjectInstance(SerialContext.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:514)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Error in creating active RAR
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ActiveRAFactory.createActiveResourceAdapter(ActiveRAFactory.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ResourceAdapterAdminServiceImpl.createActiveResourceAdapter(ResourceAdapterAdminServiceImpl.java:212)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.createActiveResourceAdapter(ConnectorRuntime.java:379)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.naming.ConnectorObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ConnectorObjectFactory.java:108)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.gjc.spi.ResourceAdapterImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ActiveRAFactory.createActiveResourceAdapter(ActiveRAFactory.java:101)
    ... 19 more
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you datasource is not working.  Are you trying to run Glassfish inside NetBeans?  Maybe try running it externally.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found the answer to this one. It's obvious that there isn't a clear understanding of JPA users. The answer isn't to just change from ext to in or vice versa. I did not need JTA; I'm using a local resource, so I had to follow the local config in persistence.xml which I found on:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Runtime#Java_Standard_Edition.